# error: no match for operator= in map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, rapidxml

im trying to import data from an XML file and save them in a 5D map

```
// declaration of the map
    map<char *, map<char *, map<char*, map<char *, map<char*, map<char*, char*, cmp_str>, cmp_str>, cmp_str>, cmp_str>, cmp_str>, cmp_str> XmlData;
```

im using for the XML-Parsing the RapidXML Parser

```
file<> xmlFile("jobs.xml");
xml_document<> doc;
doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());

xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node();
while(node != 0) {
    xml_node<> *child = node->first_node();
    while (child != 0)
    {
       xml_node<> *subchild = child->first_node();
       while (subchild != 0)
       {
           xml_node<> *subsubchild = subchild->first_node();
           while (subsubchild != 0)
           {
               xml_node<> *subsubsubchild = subchild->first_node();
               while (subsubsubchild != 0)
               {
                  // the error appears here
                  XmlData[node->name()][child->name()][subchild->name()][subsubchild->name()][subsubsubchild->name()] = subsubsubchild->value();
                  subsubsubchild = subsubsubchild->next_sibling();
               }
               subsubchild = subsubchild->next_sibling();
           }
           subchild = subchild->next_sibling();
       }
       child = child->next_sibling();
    }
    node = node->next_sibling();
}
```

I had to use 5 while loops to iterate all nodes

XML :

```
<Job>
    <UserJob>
        <RuleSet>
            <def>
                <Path>detection_c_new.dcp</Path>
                <WkspName>MyWS</WkspName>
                <UserName>Admin</UserName>
            </def>
        </RuleSet>
    </UserJob>
    <Scenes>
        <Scene1>
            <Info>
                <def>
                    <ID>0</ID>
                    <Name>Scene 1</Name>
                </def>
            </Info>
            <Layers>
                <Layer1>
                    <Index>0</Index>
                    <Name>Layer 1</Name>
                    <ImgPath>CTX_MEM_Detail.jpg</ImgPath>
                </Layer1>
            </Layers>
            <ExpItems>
                <ExpItem1>
                    <Name>MyStats1</Name>
                    <Driver>CSV</Driver>
                    <Type>1</Type>
                        <Path>CTX_MEM_Detail.csv</Path>
                </ExpItem1>
            </ExpItems>
        </Scene1>
    </Scenes>
</Job>
```

When compiling using g++ with c++0x under CentOS 6 i get this following error:

```
Job.cpp:133: error: no match for âoperator=â in â((std::map<char*, std::map<char*, char*, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, char*> > >, cmp_str, std::all$
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:251: note: candidates are: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compa$
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:266: note:                 std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compa$
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:286: note:                 std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compa$
```

Comment: IT is important to provide the full error messages. The errors shown above are cut down and don´t show all the info. In particular you want to read the first line, and check what the types at both sides of the expression are. You will probably realize that you are assigning the wrong things. Other than that, I don't particularly like the idea of a 5-level map as you are doing... consider building a tree or using the existing tree type in the xml library

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. An xml file would be better represented as a tree not as maps with-in maps.

Comment: @svk: No, he is providing his own comparison

Comment: Oh, you're right, there is no comparison problem here. Deleting the comment.

Comment: @svk as David Rodríguez - dribeas im using my own comparison

Comment: @andre
error: no match for âoperator<<â in âstd::cout << ((std::map<char*, std::map<char*, char*, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, char*> > >, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, std::map<char*, char*, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, char*> > > > > >*)((std::map<char*, std::map<char*, std::map<char*, char*, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, char*> > >, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, std::map<char*, char*, cmp_str, std::allocator<std::pair<char* const, char*> > > > > >
..............
the error is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char* is an awful thing to have as map key, and probably value too.

You might use const char* as key is absolutely sure that you pass pointers to stable things, like literal only.

The baseline soulution would use string as both key and payload, and I guess your problem would go away too. The most probable immediate cause is that your value refuses to convert to char*.